# Importing JAR file in Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I have created titanium mobile module project and copied .zip file to /lib folder and added entry to classpath. What are the next things I have to do So that I can access the method from JAR file. And in which file I should write code for making the use of methods of JARs.

Comment: Please Help. It's urgent.Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to copy zip file in root folder of your titanium project not the lib folder. When you will run the project it will be uncompressed and it will make modules folder in root folder.
You should have an entry in TiApp.xml file something like this:

```
<modules>
    <module>
        com.test.module
    </module>
</modules>
```

and if you find folder "yourprojectdirectory->modules->android->com.test.module" then I think everything is ok....

Comment: ok, I have done the thing which you are telling and also added entry in tiapp.xml. and then built the project but it is showing me error "Requested module not found".I am using mac and what are the possible causes of getting this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have made this entry but it is still giving me error "Requested module not found". and also it's not extracting the .zip file.

Comment: Zip file gets extracted when you run the project. If zip is at root folder and you right click on project and select "Install to android device", it should extract the zip file. Not sure for running on emulator.

Comment: No, this option is also failed. Is anything there which I should try??

Comment: I really doubt that you are putting this zip file at some wrong place. please let me know the full path for (1)project folder directory[something like \titanium_workspace\projectName1\],(2) where you are copying the zip file [\titanium_workspace\projectName1\mymodule.zip]

Comment: The paths are right but you've doubt so posting these 1)project directory:Titanium Studio Workspace/GUIs 2)Zip path:Titanium Studio Workspace/GUIs/Fastpaywsdk.zip and my project type is titanium mobile project 3)my .zip file contains two modules inside it..and both modules having all files like src,gen,lib,res ...so not getting what to do??

Comment: Hey dhairya, thanks for your support...The problem was in .zip file which i had got from third party..I took it into proper format and then it worked

Comment: @Rohith I am having a similar problem (https://github.com/liccowee/Google-Cloud-Messaging--Titanium-/issues/16) can you share what was the problem in your case and how you solved it?